# In AngularJS how to enable swipe function for md-tabs in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I try to activate the swipe function for the material `md-tabs`, but it doesn't work. In the Manuals https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs are a parameter called "md-swipe-content", its a boolean -  How can I activate this parameter and enable the swiping for the md-tabs?

Comment: Your link is not about Google Material Design, it's a link to **Angular** Material. Are you developing for Android or AngularJS?

Comment: Ohh sry, yeah i mean angular material. I am developing for AngularJS :)

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/swipe   ,  http://codepen.io/pen/ from documentation Give a try

Comment: Ohh, must i add the "swipe" function manually from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/swipe for each tab? I thought the "md-swipe-content='ture'" parameter does that in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too! I think the md-swipe-content attribute for md-tabs is broken for 1.10.0-rc1. I downgraded to 1.0.6 and this resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks! i changed the css and it works fine with the md-swipe-content="true" parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You just set it on the tabs?

```
<md-tabs md-swipe-content="true>
  <md-tab label="one">
    <md-content>
      ....
    </md-content>
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't for me, i copy the code (with closed "true") from your examle. But the swipe function on the browser (with mouse) and on the mobile device with trouch doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide more information then. Browser etc. and tell us if other swipe components work. Swipe-demo, toasts etc.

Comment: thanks for the help, the issue was the css version - see Jd Geier´s answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add **md-swipe-content** into **md-tabs**

```
<md-tabs md-swipe-content="true">
...
</md-tabs>
```

[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwoOwN) an example show the swipe function with angular material